# Error al subir un archivo, desde una aplicacion (Front-End Angular, BackEnd C#) Error del IIS 500 0 64 30465

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, proxy

**Buenas**
Tengo una aplicacion el cual su frontEnd es Angular el cual esta en una red DMZ y BackEnd esta hecho en C# y montado en un IIS en red interna, el paso de request del metodo post se realiza mediante un HAPROXY el cual esta montado en LINUX , el error que lanza es el error 500 0 64 30465, no me graba nada en el log del back solo en el log del IIS.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Tengo una aplicacion hecha en C# para el BackEnd, y angular para el Front End los dos estan separados en sitios diferentes en IIS diferentes uno con una IP 238 y otra con 245 cuando publico mi aplicacion con un servicio DNS y un HAPROXY como mediador de las consultas, me da un error al alzar un archivo me da error 500, se loggea sin problema y puedo cargar y modificar registros, solo al alzar un archivo desde fuera da ese error.